# In Remix JS how does one utilise useLocation?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

My error code: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

In my project I have a Layout component, within this component i'm rendering a Sidenav component. Within the Sidenav component; I'm trying to utilise the "useLocation" package from "@remix-run/react": (use-case: breadcrumb navigation).

The Layout.jsx file is rendering within the root.jsx file (./app/root.jsx). See below for root.jsx:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Document>
      <MaterialUIControllerProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Outlet />
        </Layout>
      </MaterialUIControllerProvider>
    </Document>
  );
}
```

and here is how i'm using useLocation:

```
 import { Link, NavLink,useLocation } from "@remix-run/react";



// fix current error: cannot read undefined pathname

function Sidenav(props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { pathname } = location;
  console.log(pathname)
  _pathName = pathname;
  collapseName = _pathName.split("/").slice(1)[0];
  return (<></>)
}
```

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location

Comment: Already tried this mate.. react-router-dom is replaced by "@remix-run/react"

Comment: It would help if you actually showed how you use `useLocation`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own answer.. in a way.

Imported useLocation from react-router-dom (react-router-dom@6.0.0).. now i'm seeing a different error: Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a  component.

.. which means I've progressed but only slightly.. .. .

Unfortunately, this component is not a Router component. So what I've decided to do is to implement a Breadcrumb component which is utilised by Router components; fingers crossed

Answer (score 0):

In Remix, you can use `useLocation` hook to retrieve information for `pathname`. From your code, looks like that, you might be getting an error while doing `slice` on `pathname` value.

[Demo app on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/remixjs-access-pathname-from-uselocation-hook-rq9xqk?file=%2Fapp%2Froutes%2Findex.tsx%3A6%2C28)

##### Reference Code

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Index() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const segments = pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{pathname}</h1>
      <h3>
        <ul>
          {segments.map((d) => (
            <li key={d}>{d}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </h3>
      <Link to="/child">Child Route</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```